# Updating multiple records using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5. I am looking for a better approach to update multiple records.

People are talking about [EF Extensions](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). But I am not sure how to use it with my scenario.

This is my method signature.

```
internal void Update( List<Models.StockItem> stockItemsUpdate)
```

I need to update all the corresponding `stockitem` entities.

```
using (var context = new  eCommerceEntities())
{
   var items = context.StockItems.Where(si => stockItemsUpdate.Select(it => it.ID).Contains(si.ID));
}
```

I believe above query will return those entities.

How can I use EF extensions in this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `EntityFramework.Extended`'s [`BatchExtensions`](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Extensions/BatchExtensions.cs) there is an `Update` extension method with this signature:

```
public static int Update<TEntity>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> updateExpression)
```

You can use this as follows:

```
items.Update(item => new StockItem { Stock = 0 });
```

to set the stock of the selected items to 0.

Comment: After looking at its git repository. It seems to be a very buggy library.